# HTML Table : Overflow-x scroll if no of columns are more

Tags: css, html-table

I have a table with certain columns. If I add columns then the table div should scroll horizontally.

Let say I have 10 columns and I add 2 more columns.

so I want there is no scroll up to 10 columns and If there are 2 more columns , then There should be `overflow-x:scroll`.

```css
.horizontal_scroll_div{
  
}

.horizontal_scroll_div .scroll_table_div{
  overflow-x: scroll !important;
}

.horizontal_scroll_div .scroll_table_div .table_section{
  width:1200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="horizontal_scroll_div">
    <div class="scroll_table_div b">
      <div class="table_section">
      <div class="row m-l-none m-r-none " >
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 set_padding_0">
                <div class="table-responsive m-b-none no_border">
                <table class="table b-t b-b no-footer">
                  <thead class="bg-white">
                  <tr>
                    <th>column 1</th>
                    <th>column 2</th>
                    <th>column 3</th>
                    <th>column 4</th>
                    <th>column 5</th>
                    <th>column 6</th>
                    <th>column 7</th>
                    <th>column 8</th>
                    <th>column 9</th>
                    <th>column 10</th>
                    <th>column 11</th>
                    <th>column 12</th>
                    
                  </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>value 1</td>
                    <td>value 2</td>
                    <td>value 3</td>
                    <td>value 4</td>
                    <td>value 5</td>
                    <td>value 6</td>
                    <td>value 7</td>
                    <td>value 8</td>
                    <td>value 9</td>
                    <td>value 10</td>
                    <td>value 11</td>
                    <td>value 12</td>
                  </tr>
                  </tbody>
                  </table>
               </div>
          </div>
       </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Any help would be great.
Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Set a fixed width for the ten columns so that adding extra columns would be more than the fixed width, leading to a scroll appearing. In which case you can use

```
overflow-x:auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I think you should manually set css change.
For example. 10 columns 100 width without scroll, 12 - with scroll

```
    .column{width: 100px;} #its 10x100 = 1000px

     @media screen and (min-width: 1001px)  {
         .table {overflow-x: scroll;}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

When width is reach `1200px` after that the scroll bar appear.

```
.horizontal_scroll_div .scroll_table_div{
  overflow-x: auto !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
overflow-x: auto !important;
```

inside div class

```
.horizontal_scroll_div .scroll_table_div
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem and it was resolved by applying below style to the `<table>` element.

```
display:block;
overflow-x: scroll;
```